# LibGit2Sharp Renamed files

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, libgit2sharp

I am a bit confused whether LibGit2Sharp supports detecting renamed files or not. 
I have a program which uses the LibGit2Sharp library. I can detect Unaltered files and modified files but i cannot detect renamed files.

```
RetrieveStatus (String)
```

The files are created in a c# program, so I know which files I renamed. Is it possible to change the filestatus of a file in LibGit2Sharp to "renamed"?

I want to get the history of a file but sometimes this file is renamed. I want to get the full history, meaning also the renamed files. What would be the best approach for this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detection of renaming though the `Index.RetrieveStatus()` API has been introduced in LibGit2Sharp with **[PR #523](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/523)**.

For performance reasons, by default, detection of renamed files isn't done. One have to explicitly set the behavioral flags through the **[StatusOptions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/StatusOptions.cs#L32-L64)** type.

The **[StatusFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/StatusFixture.cs#L148-L241)** suite showcases some renaming detection tests that should help you tackle this.